# Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error

Tags: 16.04, unity, compiz

I just upgraded to 16.04 from 14.04 and I keep getting this error everytime I reboot my machine. How to resolve this issue? Is this a missing package issue?

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is related to your problem, but it look very similar.  Take a look at comment 7 in the below link for a possible work around.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/signon-ui/+bug/1235742

> There is a workaround to this problem that worked for me. From the
>   terminal execute the following:
>
> ```
> sudo apt --reinstall install signon-ui
> sudo apt --reinstall install signon-ui-x11
> sudo apt --reinstall install signon-ui-service
> sudo reboot
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Check the "Ignore future promlems of this type" in lower left corner, and press "Continue" in the lower right corner .. and answer further pop-up windows, if any. Your system will propably work okay now.

This is not due to missing packets or other thing you have done wrong. At some time this software error might be fixed.

Update your system to get fixes and security updates, open a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and reboot.

Comment: It is probably useful to explain what are you ignoring... It is often not recommended to ignore errors popped by diagnostic systems.

Comment: The OP is not asking for a way to ignore or hide the problem; they're asking for a way to know what's causing the problem and how to actually get it fixed.